# Dropdown in webgrid on edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have web grid in MVC for displaying data and edit button to edit fields on this grid.
But I want to put dropdown(data will be filled from database) instead of Textbox for Country,State column. How can I do it?

```
    grid1.Column("Name", "Name", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblName"  >@item.Name</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Name" value="@item.Name" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),                         
    grid1.Column("Age", "Age", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAge"  >@item.Age</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Age" value="@item.Age" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),                     
    grid1.Column("Country", "Country", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblCountry"  >@item.Country</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Country" value="@item.Country" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),  
grid1.Column("State", "State", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblState"  >@item.State</label> </span> <input type="text" id="State" value="@item.State" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
```